# How to add link Labels at run time in Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, label

I have been making a Windows Form Application in C# using the Visual C# 2008 IDE.
 There are basically two forms in my application. One is created at Runtime and it's layout is undefined and the second one's predefined.
Now, I have been adding form elements using the toolbox provided and don't have any idea how to add them using written code(not using toolbox). I want to add   n number of Labels to the second form which is undefined. n can be anything(decided at runtime, depending on the user's input). Can anybody tell me what is the efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a quick example of a "dynamic control" being created at run-time and added to the form:

```
Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.Text = "Hello World!";
lbl.Location = new Point(100, 25);
this.Controls.Add(lbl);
```

You can replace "this" with the container to add it to, like "panel1" for instance.  For containers that have their own layout engine, like a FlowLayoutPanel, then you wouldn't need to specify a Location().

Answer (score 1):

Create a `new LinkLabel()`, set its properties (in particular, text and position), then add it to the `Controls` collection of your form or any panel.

You may also want to add event handlers, and store them somewhere (probably in a `List<T>`) so you can change or remove them later.

Answer (score 1):

Create one in the designer, configure it's properties as you wish. Then go to the designer file, which name is like `Form1.Desiner.cs`, copy the code related to your LinkLabel (find everything with text search) and paste it where you wish :)